# JEST Testing for Axios - transformResponse

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios, code-coverage

I have following axios get code which uses transformResponse

```
const downloadAttachment = ({attachmentId, id, oId}) => {
  return axios.get(`${url}/attachments/file/${attachmentId}/v1`, {
    headers: buildHeaders(),
    params: getUrlSearchParams({id, oId}),
    responseType: 'blob',
    timeout: REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
    transformResponse: [(data) => ({file: data})],
  });
};
```

I am using JEST for unit testing. I could get unit test passed with following code

```
it('should call milo with correct arguments', () => {
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockdownloadAttachmentUrl, {
      headers: mockHeaders,
      params: {
        id: 'ABCD',
        oId: 'XYZ',     
      },
      responseType: 'blob',
      timeout: 5000,
      transformResponse: [expect.any(Function)],
    });
  });
```

However JEST is not able to complete 100% code coverage and pointing to line transformResponse: [(data) => ({file: data})] in code which is not covered. How to write test to cover this part of code? Please advice.

Comment: To test that callback you'd have to explicitly invoke it by accessing the args that were passed to axios.get. This is the problem with mocking things you don't own, the mock becomes more and more complicated as you use more of the dependency's interface, and your tests become coupled to implementation details. Instead I'd suggest 1. pushing Axios behind a facade and mocking that (that the facade works can be verified at an E2E level); or 2. Using [msw](https://mswjs.io/) (or nock, or ...) to mock at the transport layer, independent of the library being used to make the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to increase coverage and keep it simple, you can use the following way:

You can use `.mockImplementationOnce()` to mock `axios.get()` method, then you can get the `transformResponse` option in your test case. You can test it as usual.

`index.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

export const downloadAttachment = ({ attachmentId, id, oId }) => {
  return axios.get(`${url}/attachments/file/${attachmentId}/v1`, {
    responseType: 'blob',
    transformResponse: [(data) => ({ file: data })],
  });
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { downloadAttachment } from './';
import axios from 'axios';

describe('66579132', () => {
  it('should transform response', async () => {
    const mRes = {};
    let transformResponse;
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockImplementationOnce((url, options) => {
      transformResponse = options!.transformResponse![0];
      return Promise.resolve(mRes);
    });
    await downloadAttachment({ attachmentId: 1, id: 1, oId: 1 });
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalled();

    // test tranfromResponse
    const response = transformResponse('teresa teng');
    expect(response).toEqual({ file: 'teresa teng' });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66579132/index.test.ts
  66579132
    ✓ should transform response (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.393 s
```